# PHP Get Methods

Tags: php, methods, get

is it possible to make

```
header("location: ../../index.php?page=account?msg=changesuccess");
```

so I want 2 messages. 
1. is page=account and in index.php it does:

```
elseif($page == "account"){
    require_once("frontend/pages/accountsettings/account.php");
}
```

2. message is, once I open account.php from above, msg=changesuccess

Comment: Thank you, it worked with "&". I didn't do that parse part.  And at this point of knowledge I don't know what does that mean xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're setting `$page` with

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

You just need to change the query string in your URL to add the `msg` parameter properly.

```
header("location: ../../index.php?page=account&msg=changesuccess");
```

Then you can get it from `$_GET` as well. Since you're using `require_once` to load account.php, any variables in index.php will be available in account.php as well.

```
// ...

elseif($page == "account"){
    $message = $_GET['msg'];
    require_once("frontend/pages/accountsettings/account.php");
    //account.php will have access to $message
}
```

You don't really need to create another variable, because account.php will also be able to access `$_GET` directly, but I just wanted to show that anything in index.php will be [in scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope) in account.php as well.

Comment: I get it now. But there is an error in last piece of code you wrote.
it goes like
$message = $_GET['msg'];

Comment: Oh, you're right of course, my mistake. Feel free to suggest an edit for typos like that in the future. I'd definitely accept an edit like that, and I think most others would as well.